# Following Twitch API parameters, but error as output

Tags: postman, twitch

I am using the twitch API just to test it out to fetch the top games

I get my app access token after making an app by passing in a POST to:

`https://id.twitch.tv/oauth2/token?client_id=<my client id>&client_secret=<my generated secret>&grant_type=client_credentials`

I then take the access token (token_type: bearer) to the actual data fetching API and do a GET request on Postman to

`https://api.twitch.tv/helix/games/top?Authorization=Bearer <access token form above>&client-id=<client-ID>`

This is my output:

```json
{
    "error": "Unauthorized",
    "status": 401,
    "message": "OAuth token is missing"
}
```

I have tried this with and without the client ID. The documentation [here](https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/api/reference#get-top-games) says that it can take an OAuth token or an app access token as the authorization parameter.

What gives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ClientID and Authorization items are *headers* not *query string parameters*

So in postman you have provided them in the wrong place

Comment: Yep appreciate it. I figured this out a few weeks ago but appreciate leaving an answer here.